# How to escape from '!' symbol in HQL

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, hql, criteria

Can any one please help to escape from NOT(!) symbol in HQL. I am using Postgres 8.3. Also I am unable to search with these chars  |\?'( )

```
fts('english',COLUMN_NAME,'" + searchText + "') = true)
```

Comment: The title is misleading I guess.

Comment: You should read a guide on SQL injection and review your entire code base.  https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be [binding](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions) the search text instead of concatenating it manually to the query. Not only does it fixes your problem, it's also better in terms of security (SQL injection) and performance (the database sees the same query with different parameters, which allows it to cache the compiled query when it can).

Change your query so it looks like:

```
fts('english', COLUMN_NAME, :searchText) = true // using named parameters
// or
fts('english', COLUMN_NAME, ?) = true // using positional parameters
```

You can then properly bind your parameters:

```
session.createQuery(hqlQuery)
        .setString("searchText", searchText)
        .iterate();
// or
session.createQuery(hqlQuery)
        .setString(0, searchText)
        .iterate();
```

It's the same principle as using a `PreparedStatement` with JDBC and setting the parameters (the main difference being that the parameters' indices start at 1 with JDBC and 0 with HQL).

Comment: I am still getting the following error.
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no operand in tsquery: "!".

Comment: That's because you're not passing a valid query to the full text search. That's a PostgreSQL issue, not an Hibernate one. Full text search usually does word stemming anyway, so punctuation will be removed and you won't be able to include it in the search. Maybe you should use [`to_tsquery()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-textsearch.html) to wrap your search text into a correct query.

Comment: @RamarajKaruppusamy For SQL injection see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and http://bobby-tables.com/